# why select options value not binded when editing entity angular 2

Tags: angular

Hello I just ran to an issue, when I try to edit i have a dropdownlist, and it does not show any value seems like it does not want to bind... Here is my code and result:

View:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectedCategory"
  required
  [(ngModel)]="subCategory.category" name="selectedCategory">
  <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]="category">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>`
```

Here is my entities:

`category.ts` class:

```
import { ICategory } from "../interfaces/icategory";

export class Category implements ICategory {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    image: string;
}
```

`subcagory.ts` class:

```
import { ISubCategory } from "../interfaces/isubcategory";
import { ICategory } from "../interfaces/icategory";

export class SubCategory implements ISubCategory {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    image: string;
    category: ICategory;
}
```

and here is the result what I can receive in developers console through debugging:

[image]

and if i go to the form there is empty DDL, but there are values for all my categories...

[image]

Has anyone got any idea where i go wrong ? :) Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The value `[(ngModel)]="subCategory.category"` refers to has to be the **same instance** than the value used in `<option *ngFor="let category of categories"`

If it's only an object with the same content, this is not enought. What count's is object identity, not content.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If it isn't the same, then there is no way to get it selected by default. You can use the default value to look up the correct instance in `categories` by comparing it's properties and then make the found instance the default. This way it's ensured that it's the exact same instance.